# Rails 5, Concerns - how to use methods in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport-concern

I am trying to learn how to use model concerns in my Rails 5 app.

I have a nested model with:

```
class Stance::Cost < ApplicationRecord

    include HasCostPolicy

    belongs_to :organisation, inverse_of: :cost
```

In my models/concerns folder, I have:

```
module HasCostPolicy
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    enum cost_sharing: {
                    proportionately: 1,
                    equally: 2,
                    no_contribution: 3,
                    bear_all_costs: 4,
                    other_cost_policy: 5

                  }
    end
end
```

Then in my nested form for cost, I have:

```
<%= f.input :ip_expenses, as: :select, label: "Responsibility for IP expenses", collection: Stance::Cost.cost_sharing.map { |key, val| [key.humanize, key] } %>
```

When I try to render the organisation form (wiht the nested cost fields), I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `cost_sharing' for #<Class:0x007ffe7eaef220>
```

What do I need to do in order to be able to use the HasCostPolicy concern in my nested form?

Comment: is `Stance::Cost.cost_sharing` defined in rails console?

Comment: @maxpleaner - no. c = Stance::Cost.new
 => #<Stance::Cost id: nil, organisation_id: nil, ip_expenses: nil, ip_note: nil, diligence_expenses: nil, diligence_note: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.3.1p112 :009 > c.cost_sharing = 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `cost_sharing=' for #<Stance::Cost:0x007f9c5e7f28d8>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely, I need to pluralise cost_sharing in the form.

I don't understand why, but this works:

```
<%= f.input :ip_expenses, as: :select, label: "Responsibility for IP expenses", collection: Stance::Cost.cost_sharings.map { |key, val| [key.humanize, key] } %>
```

Comment: on the class (`Stance::Cost`) the plural method is defined, and returns a hash with all possible values. But on instances (`Stance::Cost.new`) the singular is defined, and it returns a string.

Comment: I don't understand what that means. The method isn't defined as a plural in the concern. The enum is defined as "cost_sharing" (singular).

Comment: yeah, rails creates the plural method for you for the class. The

Comment: I just don't understand what you mean. If I define the enum as singular,do you mean that rails automatically converts it to the plural?

Comment: I haven't used enuns much but that's what it seems like is happening. I wouldn't be terribly surprised anyway, rails often does tricks with pluralization / camel case / underscore

Comment: Where can I learn about these rules. I haven't seen that come up at all in any of the tutorials I've read about concerns.

Comment: see [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). It makes sense if you think about it. Say you have an enum `status`. For the instance you have singular, i.e. _what is the status?_. For the class you have plural i.e. _what are the possible statuses?_